# How can i access the variables on a terminal, which got set while executing the tcl program?

Tags: tcl

How can I access the variable which got set while executing a TCL program from a terminal? Please help.

Regards,
Sagar

Comment: I'm trying to understand why the trivial `puts $varName` isn't an obvious answer. It depends on what you mean by “executing” and “access”…

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to running a script with tclsh from a prompt, just have the script write a temp file containing the value of the variable. I interpreted your question as, how do I preserve the variables value after the script end, but could be way off base there